# How to Disable a Form element (textbox) if sql query retrieve no row as result

Tags: html, vbscript, asp-classic

*I want to  make a textbox read only or disable if sql query retrieves no rows as result.  What shall i write to make the textbox "text1" disabled/read only*

```
<% 
    Set ObjRs=ObjConn.Execute(strSQL)

    if not ObjRs.EOF then

    CMSPI = ObjRs("CMSPI")
    else
    < Here i need to disable / make read only the combo box>

    end if

    %>

   <HTML>
   <Table>
   <form method="POST" action="Dis****.asp" name="Form1">
   <Tr>
   <Td>
     <input type="text" id="idtext1"   name="text1" />
     </td>                                    
          </tr>
</table>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably make it work if you use something like this

```
document.getElementById("idtext1").style.display = "none";
```

Comment: If we do that we get an error . But i found the solution..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
<% 
    Dim isDisabled
    Set ObjRs=ObjConn.Execute(strSQL)

    if not ObjRs.EOF then
        CMSPI = ObjRs("CMSPI")
    else
        isDisabled = " disabled"
    end if

    %>

   <HTML>
   <Table>
   <form method="POST" action="Dis****.asp" name="Form1">
   <Tr>
   <Td>
     <input type="text" id="idtext1"   name="text1" / <%= isDisabled%>>
     </td>                                    
          </tr>
</table>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes, I found the solution which is similar to yours.. Thank you :)